# Using mathematical symbols alpha, beta, implies in latex

Tags: math-mode, symbols

How can I use the mathematical symbols like alpha, beta, implies and many more symbols in the tex file?

Comment: Use the math mode `$\alpha,\beta$`

Comment: You can learn more about math and LaTeX in Herberts [mathmode](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/voss-mathmode).

Comment: Hello! I hope I won't sound harsh, but from your question it seems to me that you lack some basic LaTeX knowledge. I would like to suggest you to take reasonable amount of time and learn the crucial basics, for good resources see [_What are good learning resources for a LaTeX beginner?_](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11/).

Comment: ‘implies’ is `\Rightarrow`.

Comment: @Bernard or `\implies` ;)

Comment: @Sigur Can anyone please help, if I want to use `$\alpha$` instead of `\alpha` what do I change in the `\userpackage`? It is giving me an error on overleaf when I use `$\alpha$`

Comment: @FareedAF, sorry, I didn't understand. Observe that `\usepackage` not `user`. Also, `\alpha` should be in math mode, inside some `$   $` and it is a basic comand, should work without any addtional package.

Comment: @Sigur There's an overflow when simply used `\alpha`; all the text after that overflows out of the page. Even this doesn't work, `\mathrm{\alpha}`. And only this ` $\alpha$ ` because of the prefixed, suffixed spaces. (at least in my case) - FareedAF might have faced the same issue

Answer (score 13, accepted):

LaTeX needs to know beforehand that the subsequent text does indeed contain mathematical elements. This is because LaTeX typesets maths notation differently from normal text. Therefore, special environments have been declared for this purpose.

Greek letters are commonly used in mathematics, and they are very easy to type in math mode. You just have to type the name of the letter after a backslash: if the first letter is lowercase, you will get a lowercase Greek letter, if the first letter is uppercase (and only the first letter), then you will get an uppercase letter. Note that some uppercase Greek letters look like Latin ones, so they are not provided by LaTeX (e.g. uppercase Alpha and Beta are just "A" and "B" respectively). Lowercase epsilon, theta, kappa, phi, pi, rho, and sigma are provided in two different versions. The alternate, or variant, version is created by adding "var" before the name of the letter:

`\alpha`, `A`, `\beta`, `B`, `\gamma`, `\Gamma`, `\pi`, `\Pi`, `\phi`, `\varphi`, `\Phi`

See more in: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Mathematics

Comment: You might mention that mathmode is invoked inline with `$` or `\(`, `\)` delimiters, and on a separate line with `\[`, `\]` delimiters, as well as various math environments.  Welcome to the site.

Comment: There's an overflow when simply used `\alpha`; all the text after that overflows out of the page. Even this doesn't work, `\mathrm{\alpha}`. And only this ` $\alpha$ ` because of the prefixed, suffixed spaces. (at least in my case)

Answer (score 3):

You might want to try the "amsmath" package. Use `\usepackage{amsmath}` in the preamble of your document. Then one way to get an equation with greek letter is:

```
\begin{equation}\label{eq1}
    \alpha + \beta_1
\end{equation}
```

Comment: Don't give labels like `eq1`. describe the contents in a keyword, like `\label{eq:alphaBetaSum}`.

Comment: Can you please help, if I want to use `$\alpha$` instead of `\alpha` what do I change in the `\userpackage`? It is giving me an error on overleaf when I use `$\alpha$`